# RAID controller overheats in certain cases

Tags: raid, hardware-raid

I've been having problems with my builds' RAID controller overheating. I found that the case is to blame, but I can't figure out how and why it would do that.

I used to use 4U CompuCase RA455A00 for client's server builds but apparently, they're discontinued or at least our supplier doesn't sell them anymore. So I looked for a new case to use and settled with 4U Chenbro RM41300-F1.

All is well until I found out that the RAID controller (Adaptec 8405e) goes up to 70C, which I didn't think was normal. I started switching parts to pinpoint what's causing it to heat up. First I switched the RAID controller to a different port, then I changed the RAID controller to a new one (same model). then the motherboard, power supply, cpu, ram, fans, the SSDs, the cables, and even the motherboard standoffs, but The RAID is still not cooling down.

Then I took the whole build as is and transferred it to one of the old case I've been using (the CompuCase one) and the RAID controller never went above 45C. I even left it running overnight. I've built a couple more machines with the new case and the RAID controller overheats, so I'm sure it's definitely the (Chenbro) case that's the problem, but it's weird that it would cause that.

Is this a known problem? Can cases actually cause components to overheat? How do I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [Adaptec specifications sheet](https://www.microsemi.com/document-portal/doc_download/136397-microsemi-adaptec-series-8e-product-brief):

> **Operating temperature:** 0 °C to 55 °C (with 200 LFM airflow). Note: ***This adapter contains a powerful RAID processor that requires adequate
>   airflow to operate reliably***. Only install this card into server or PC
>   chassis with at least 200 LFM airflow. Temperature measured 1 inch
>   from RAID adapter.

Maybe your first case/server has poor airflow on the PCI-E slots zone, or something heats up the air around the card.

As suggested, you should solve attaching a small fan to the heatspreader.

Answer (score 5):

Install active fan. It’s $2 :) Alternatively you can go software RAID and XOR checksums will heat your CPU rather than RAID card FPGA or ASIC.

Comment: Thanks. But why is the RAID controller overheating when it's in one case and not the other?